# Refund Stripe Charge after payment verification (Best practice)

Tags: stripe-payments

I was wondering what is the best practice to refund a charge that was only made for verification. Lets assume a customer updates his/her card while having an active subscription. To make sure a charge can be made to that new card, I create a small charge of 50 cent.

Of course, the customer will get these 50 cents back. Right now, I start the refund about a second after I made that charge.

I was wondering if that is the best practice. I know a bunch of companies do that, but the refund usually appears about 1-5 days later, not right after making the payment. Is this common, or should I use a cronjob to refund a day later or so? I was just wondering if there is any potential downside of refunding right away.

Comment: This sounds like a general business practices question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be making these charges at all, so best practices about refunding them are moot.

Instead, you should use [Setup Intents to collect card details for later payments](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse#web), including [3D Secure authentication](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/3d-secure) if required.